# Moving an element with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am trying to move a div element with Javascript. I have used `setInterval` function and incremented the value. My code is:

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" type="text/css">
</head>
<button id="something"> click me </button>
<body>
<div id="insidename"><div>
<script>
var m = document.getElementById('something');
m.onclick = function() {
    var n = 0;
    window.setInterval(function() {
        var w = n++;
        document.getElementById('insidename').style.width = w;
    }, 2000);
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

## my styles.css

```
#insidename {

    border: 2px solid #a1a1a1;
    padding: 10px;
    background: #dddddd;
    width: 15px;
}
```

I just want to make the progress bar move when i click the button ..But the code which i wrote isn't working

Comment: You are resetting `n` on every click.

Comment: I think he only wants to increment it in the timer, the click resets things.

Comment: @hjpotter92 so what should i do to make it move actually ??..do i need to put the n variable inside the callback

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `width` style needs units at the end, such as `px`. So it should be:

```
document.getElementById('insidename').style.width = w+"px";
```

Comment: here the element starts moving actually ..but its only moving a slighter i just want to move continously

Comment: You're only running the function every 2 seconds, and only adding 1 pixel to the width. Run it more often and increase the amount, and it will go faster.

Comment: yup got it bro ..you have helped in in many situations ..you are great..:)gonna accept this in minutes